# Apple Business Manager access to info

Tags: apple-id, privacy

Small company of 9. We all use MacBook Air laptops controlled by Apple Business Manager. We have all been given the ok to sign into our personal Apple ID’s on our MacBook Airs.

Question… does my employer have access to read my personal email in Mail and my personal text messages in iMessage? And we use Teams for communicating internally. Can they see Teams messages 2 employees have among themselves? Can they see my personal Notes and Photos?

Comment: I don’t advise this at all; keep your personal Apple ID away from this business machine.  See this cautionary [question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/458077/119271 ) for details.

Comment: Yes to all questions.